# Error in converting Varchar into Datetime for calculating DateDiff in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the difference in seconds between two these dates. However these columns - `WA4.EVENT_DATTIM` and `WA4.EVENT_DATTIM1` - are stored as `VARCHAR(52)`.

I am getting the error below when trying to convert it to `datetime` and

```
SELECT
    DATEDIFF(SS, CONVERT(INTEGER, (CONVERT(DATETIME, WA4.EVENT_DATTIM))),
                 CONVERT(INTEGER, (CONVERT(DATETIME, WA4.EVENT_DATTIM1))))
FROM 
    TableA AS WA4
```

Error in SQL Server:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
>
> State: 22008, Native: 242,
>   Origin: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]

Please provide your inputs how to resolve the error.

Thanks.

Comment: can you give an example of how the dates are stored in the event_dattim column.

Comment: Why would you have CONVERT(INTEGER,... in there?

Comment: @Alam - the value in event_dattim is 2017-08-11-12:30:32.456788

Comment: Simply put one of the values in EVENT_DATTIM1 or event_dattim is not valid.  Such as 2017-02-30.  I'd Start off by parting out the strings into Distinct years months and days and scan for an invalid month month-day, or even year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If 2012+ use TRY_CONVERT().  This will return a NULL if the conversion fails.

**Example**

```
select DATEDIFF(SS,
                TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, WA4.EVENT_DATTIM )
               ,TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, WA4.EVENT_DATTIM1))
FROM TableA AS WA4
```

**To Identify the problem records**

```
Select * From TableA 
 where TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, WA4.EVENT_DATTIM ) is null
   or  TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, WA4.EVENT_DATTIM1) is null
```

Now, since you are converting to Seconds, you can't have a span greater than 68 years, 19 days, 3 hours, 14 minutes, and 6 seconds

> **EDIT - Perhaps the worst datetime string EVER**

Also notice we need convert to datetime2

```
Select convert(datetime2,stuff(replace(stuff('2017-06-12-21.57.58.385895',11,1,' '),'.',':'),20,1,'.'))
```

**Returns**

```
2017-06-12 21:57:58.3858950
```

> **Edit 2 - Both Fields**

```
Select DateDiff(SS,try_convert(datetime2,stuff(replace(stuff(WA4.EVENT_DATTIM,11,1,' '),'.',':'),20,1,'.'))
                  ,try_convert(datetime2,stuff(replace(stuff(WA4.EVENT_DATTIM1,11,1,' '),'.',':'),20,1,'.'))
               ) 
 From TableA AS WA4
```

> **EDIT 3 - Let's see the condition of the data**

The following will tell you what records fail the conversion

```
Select WA4.EVENT_DATTIM
 From TableA
 Where  try_convert(datetime2,stuff(replace(stuff(EVENT_DATTIM,11,1,' '),'.',':'),20,1,'.')) is null
```

and

```
Select EVENT_DATTIM1
 From TableA
 Where  try_convert(datetime2,stuff(replace(stuff(EVENT_DATTIM1,11,1,' '),'.',':'),20,1,'.')) is null
```

### Results for Edit 3

S1min                               S1max                 D1min       D1min
2011-07-19-07.53.18.603940  2017-06-12-21.57.58.385895  2011-07-19  2017-06-12

> **EDIT 4 Tell me Your Capatibility Level**

```
select name, compatibility_level , version_name = 
CASE compatibility_level
    WHEN 65  THEN 'SQL Server 6.5'
    WHEN 70  THEN 'SQL Server 7.0'
    WHEN 80  THEN 'SQL Server 2000'
    WHEN 90  THEN 'SQL Server 2005'
    WHEN 100 THEN 'SQL Server 2008/R2'
    WHEN 110 THEN 'SQL Server 2012'
    WHEN 120 THEN 'SQL Server 2014'
    WHEN 130 THEN 'SQL Server 2016'
END
from sys.databases
```

> **EDIT 5 - This Does work on 2012 compatibility level 110**

Given the results you provided, this does work.

Example (using that horrible datetime string):

```
Declare @TableA table (EVENT_DATTIM varchar(50),EVENT_DATTIM1 varchar(50))
Insert Into @TableA values
('2011-07-19-07.53.18.603940','2017-06-12-21.57.58.385895')

Select DateDiff(SS,try_convert(datetime2,stuff(replace(stuff(WA4.EVENT_DATTIM,11,1,' '),'.',':'),20,1,'.'))
                  ,try_convert(datetime2,stuff(replace(stuff(WA4.EVENT_DATTIM1,11,1,' '),'.',':'),20,1,'.'))
               ) 
 From @TableA AS WA4
```

Returns

```
186242680
```

Comment: The SQL server does not recognize the try_convert function. Do you know any other function?

Comment: @user3802118 If not 2012+ or Compatibility Level set to 110+, I would suggest select distinct EVENT_DATTIM from TableA Order by 1 ... Perhaps this will help you identity an correct bogus data  Also assuming your dates are yyyy-mm-dd or mm/dd/yyyy and NOT dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @user3802118 If date in format dd/mm/yyyy you can SET DATEFORMAT dmy

Comment: The format for the EVENT_DATTIM column is 
2017-06-12-21.57.58.385895. The challenge is to convert this field which is a VARCHAR into a DATETIME field. I  have tried different ways and I get the following errors:

Comment: @user3802118 See the EDIT in my updated answer.  Just goes to illustrate when asking questions, best to supply sample data

Comment: I tried your query above and its working fine.. but when I am using datetime2 function with the EVENT_DATTIM, query -[Select convert(datetime2, WA5.EVENT_DATTIM) 
FROM dbo.TA_Z_WA5 as WA5 ].  I am getting the same error - "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." I am really running out of ideas and patience to resolve this..

Comment: @user3802118 Just assumed you were using the techique listed a for both fields.  One moment and I will make the edit

Comment: @user3802118 See "EDIT 2"  If this does not work, then you will need scrub your data for bogus data.  This is the prime reason to store datetime as datetime and not strings.  Trust me (from experience) too many things can go wrong.

Comment: @user3802118 If EDIT 2 still fails, I can help with a query to identify the bogus/malformed datetime strings.

Comment: sorry its not working! I will need to get the data as datetime because string is not helping at all.

Comment: @user3802118  Let's back up for a moment.  Tell me what version of SQL Server you are on  Select @@version

Comment: @user3802118 See EDIT 3.  run that query and either share the results or tell me if the values look like date/time strings

Comment: Version Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3) (KB3072779) - 11.0.6020.0 (X64)

Comment: @user3802118 OK, 2012 supports try_convert().  Try_Convert() will return a NULL rather than throwing an error.  See Updated EDIT 3

Comment: @user3802118 Since you have 2012, I suspect you Compatibilty Level is not up to par.   ALTER DATABASE database_name   
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110

Comment: @user3802118 See Edit 4

Comment: Finally got your query running (Edit 5)! It was due to the Compatibility level which was set to 90. Thanks @John Cappelletti for your support and patience :)

Comment: @user3802118 Happy we got there !

Answer (score 0):

You are providing too many milliseconds. This works:

```
select convert(datetime, '2017-08-11 12:30:32.456')
```